# Возведение в степень по модулю

Tags: java, алгоритм, математика

Не могу реализовать на Java следующий алгоритм:

[image: Алгоритм возведения в степень по модулю]

При `x=5`, `y=2`, `N=4` выдает правильный результат, при `x=5`, `y=10`, `N=11` - неправильный.

```
public static double modPower(double x, double y, int N) 
{
    if(y==0) return 1;
    double z = modPower(x, y/2, N);
    if ((y % 2) == 0) 
        return (z*z)%N;
    else 
        return (x*z*z)%N;
}
```

Comment: А почему `double`? По-моему, имеются в виду целочисленные операции...

Comment: И зачем тут рекурсивный алгоритм, имхо обычный цикл понятнее.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Числа x, y и прочие должны быть **целочисленные**.

Грубо говоря, что такое `3.1415 % 2`, по-вашему? :)
Или `y/2` в третьей строке - это совсем не то, что имеется в виду в описании алгоритма...

Comment: Я еще добавлю, что x*z*z лучше разбить на 2 операции, ((x*z )%N * z )%N и использовать long не int

Comment: Немножко не понял про 3 строку -  что именно там должно быть. Изначально все было int, тоже было неверно, с double просто решил "поиграться".

Comment: @Анон Деление бывает целочисленное (грубо, 8 поделить на 3 равно 2) и с плавающей точкой (5.0 поделить на 2 равно 2.5). Намек понятен? :)

Comment: Спасибо. Понятно

Answer (score 0):

Учитывая что ввод указан как `n`-битовые числа без явной границы для `n`, то возможно следует использовать `BigInteger` вместо `double`:

```
static BigInteger modExp(BigInteger base, BigInteger exponent, BigInteger m)
{ 
  int trailing_zero_bits_count = exponent.getLowestSetBit(); 
  if (trailing_zero_bits_count == -1) // exponent == 0
    return BigInteger.ONE.mod(m);

  BigInteger z = modExp(base, exponent.shiftRight(1), m); // base**(exponent//2)% m
  BigInteger z_sq = z.pow(2).mod(m); // z**2 % m
  if (trailing_zero_bits_count != 0) // even
    return z_sq;
  return z_sq.multiply(base).mod(m); // z**2 * base % m
}
```

Стоит заметить, что данный код возвращает ноль, а не единицу для `modExp(x, 0, 1)` то есть если `y == 0`, то код не возвращает `1`—как в условии вопроса ошибочно указано—если `N == 1`, потому что `1 % 1 == 0`.